# Include unit tests in code analysis

Tags: phpunit, sonarqube

We are using SonarQube in version 6.3.1 and are quite happy with the functionality.

However we would like to include the test code to analysis. More specific include them for analysis but exclude them for duplication and code coverage.

Our current config looks like this:

```
sonar.sources=src/src
sonar.tests=src/tests, src/jsTests

sonar.test.inclusions=src/jsTests/**, src/tests/**
```

As far as we have seen, sonar automatically excludes our tests from analysis:

```
10:20:37.223 INFO  - Excluded sources:
10:20:37.223 INFO  -   **/Externals/**
10:20:37.223 INFO  -   src/jsTests/**
10:20:37.223 INFO  -   src/tests/**
10:20:37.223 INFO  - Included tests:
10:20:37.223 INFO  -   src/jsTests/**
10:20:37.223 INFO  -   src/tests/**
```

This is what we would like to change. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to raise issues from "normal" rules on test files?

Comment: Yes, we want some quality on our tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SonarJava analyzer includes test-specific rules such as [S2699](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2699) "Tests should include assertions" to analyze their fitness *as tests*. If included in your profile, those rules will run automatically against, and only against test files. "Normal" rules are not run against test files.

To analyze the quality of the code itself in your test files, you're going to need to set up a separate analysis that sets `sonar.sources` to the location of your tests. You can then set coverage and duplications exclusions as Pierre-Yves suggests, altho I'd do it via the UI, rather than in the analysis properties.

Answer (score 0):

Change your config so that your tests are considered as source files. Try something like:

```
sonar.sources=src/src, src/tests, src/jsTests
sonar.tests=
sonar.test.inclusions=
sonar.coverage.exclusions=src/tests/**, src/jsTests/**
sonar.cpd.exclusions=src/tests/**, src/jsTests/**
```

Comment: This does not work, we got the following error:
ERROR: Caused by: Error during parsing of test execution report testReport.xml
ERROR: Caused by: Line 3 of report refers to a file which is not configured as a test file: /src/jsTests/Tests/MyTest.js